# De la lourdeur du français

Tags: anglais

Je cherche une explication à ce sentiment de lourdeur chaque fois que je recommence à m'exprimer en français. C'est ma langue maternelle, je pense en avoir une bonne maîtrise (et c'est peut-être un problème en soi, cf. ci-dessous), mais depuis longtemps je n'évolue pratiquement plus que dans un environnement anglophone (anglais américain, s'il faut préciser).

Je précise que ce n'est pas la sensation d'être "rouillé". Je ne cherche pas mes mots. C'est plutôt comme si le retour au français rendait plus visible sa complexité.

J'écrivais plus haut que la maîtrise du français pouvait amener à une impression encore plus forte de lourdeur, car je crois constater que plus on a à l'esprit de règles à respecter, d'erreurs à éviter, de pièges à contourner, de subtilités associées au contexte, etc. et plus la tête travaille. C'est cet effort supplémentaire nécessaire pour bien parler ou écrire en français que je ressens, et assez négativement.

J'aimerais savoir si cette sensation de lourdeur en passant de l'anglais au français pour un individu dont la langue maternelle est le français est commune ou si en général les gens se sentent plus détendus à retrouver leur langue maternelle.

Il est évident que si la maîtrise de l'anglais est limitée et son usage laborieux, le retour au français ne peut qu'être libérateur. Mais je parle de ceux qui maîtrisent les deux langues et donc qui peuvent percevoir leurs différences structurelles.

Comment: Je pense que la question est un peu *too broad*, je la laisse ouverte pour le moment et j'attends de voir ce qu'en pense la communauté.
À titre personnel, évoluant dans un milieu régulièrement anglophone (ma compagne n'est pas française et nous parlons anglais ensemble), c'est plutôt un sentiment de soulagement qui me vient à l'esprit. Tout dépend peut-être des contextes dans lesquels tu utilises l'une ou l'autre des langues ? Par exemple, si tu parles essentiellement anglais à l'oral et dans un contexte informel, et français dans un contexte officiel/formel (tâches administratives etc.)...

Comment: C'est effectivement une piste. En fait cela m'a paru spectaculaire au moment de m'exprimer en français sur SE French Language, alors que j'évolue en temps normal sur SE Physics.

Comment: Votre discussion est des plus intéressantes ; malheureusement elle ne peut pas être poursuivie sur ce site, où les utilisateurs ne peuvent s'occuper que des difficultés de la grammaire, de la sémantique et de la prononciation du français (et de quelques autres questions comme l'étymologie ou l'histoire de la langue). Les discussions qui sont affaire d'opinion sont strictement rejetées. Votre question va être fermée.

Comment: Mais il y a des éléments de comparaison objectifs entre l'anglais et le français.

Comment: J'ai bien peur que non ; il me semble que ce qui sera un problème pour les uns ne le sera pas pour d'autres. Quels éléments objectifs, par exemple ?

Comment: Par exemple la régularité et la variété des conjugaisons.

Comment: Comment allez-vous introduire ce facteur en tant qu'influence dans le rôle de rendre la langue plus ou moins lourde à celui qui s'y remet ?

Comment: Je me trouve plus souvent à me poser de questions sur l'orthographe, la conjugaison ou l'accord corrects en français qu'en anglais, parce que je pense qu'il y a objectivement plus d'exceptions en français qu'en anglais. Je vais vérifier tel subjonctif uniquement parce que je ne veux faire aucune faute de français. Si je m'en fichais, comme beaucoup de gens de nos jours, ce serait évidemment un faux problème. Il y a aussi les tournures de phrase qui sont allongées en français.

Comment: Justement, du point de vue orthographe, j'ai moi-même certaines idées et je ne sais pas si après avoir considéré les pluriels des noms anglais la difficulté ne  serait plus grande en anglais ; ça me semble être le cas.

Comment: D'accord donc ce serait purement subjectif.

Comment: Au premier abord, oui, mais sur la base d'une étude profonde, malheureusement couteuse en temps et travail, non, je ne le crois pas: une évaluation scientifique doit exister qui doit mettre en valeur les mérites respectifs des deux langues (de façon objective, évidemment).

Comment: Je pense quand-même qu'il est assez courant d'entendre que le français est une langue difficile à apprendre, en comparaison de l'anglais. Que cette difficulté persiste à l'âge adulte, c'est peut-être différent. Mais si je prends l'exemple des dictées de Pivot, il mettait en évidence ce côté de la langue. Un élément objectif auquel je pense c'est le nombre de mots ou de syllabes pour dire la même chose. Native speaker donne quelqu'un dont c'est la langue maternelle... C'est ou bien maladroit ou bien très long.

Comment: Avez-vous une idée de la difficulté que représente l'étude des « phrasal verbs » ? Je suis sûr que vous en avez une bonne idée. Vous serez surpris de constater que si l'anglais a le plus souvent des formulations plus courtes en nombre de lettres et de mots, c'est dans un nombre non négligeables de cas l'anglais qui demande plus de mots, qui exige une plus grande spécificité.

Comment: Non je ne connais pas cette étude qui a l'air très intéressante. Est-ce qu'elle est disponible en téléchargement?

Comment: SI vous le voulez bien, continuons la discussion [sur un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113160/discussion-on-question-by-exocytosis-de-la-lourdeur-du-francais) pour éviter que tout ceci ne soit trop lourd à lire.